# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException and how to fix it?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have to make a program using Inheritance concept. I have made the base class and subclasses. But when I input the first input, it gives me Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException. How can I fix this?

These are my codes.
My main

```
package labweek7;

import java.awt.Menu;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Main {

    Vector<String> menu =new Vector<>();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    Employee emp; 
    EmployeeFullTime ft;
    EmployeePartTime pt;

    public Main() {
        int choice = 0;
        int pay;
        int time;
        int salary;


        do{
            System.out.println("ABC EMPLOYEE DATA");
            System.out.println("=================");
            System.out.println("1. Add Employee");
            System.out.println("2. View Employee");
            System.out.println("3. Resign");
            System.out.println("4. Exit");
            System.out.print("Choice: ");
            choice = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();

            switch(choice){
            case 1:
                String name = "";
                do{
                    System.out.print("Input employee name[must be more than 3 characters]: ");
                    name = scan.next();
                }while(! (name.length()>=3));
                emp.empName.add(name);

                int age;
                do{
                    System.out.print("Input employee age[>=17]: ");
                    age = scan.nextInt();
                }while(!(age>=17));
                emp.empAge.add(age);

                String role = "";
                do{
                    System.out.print("Input employee role[Assistant | Programmer](Case Sensitive): ");
                    role = scan.nextLine();
                }while(!(role.equals("Assitant") || (role.equals("Programmer"))));
                emp.empRole.add(role);

                String type = "";
                do{
                    System.out.print("Input employee type[PartTime | FullTime](Case Sensitive): ");
                    type = scan.nextLine();
                }while(!(type.equals("PartTime")|| type.equals("FullTime")));
                emp.empType.add(type);

                if(type.equals("PartTime")){
                    emp = new EmployeePartTime(name, age, role, type);
                    do{
                        System.out.print("Input pay per hour[>=10000]: ");
                        pay = scan.nextInt();
                    }while(!(pay>=10000));
                    pt.pay.add(pay);

                    do{
                        System.out.print("Input working hour per week[>0]: ");
                        time = scan.nextInt();
                    }while(!(time>0));
                    pt.hour.add(time);

                }
                else{
                    emp = new EmployeeFullTime(name, age, role, type);
                    do{
                        System.out.println("Input base salary[>=10000]: ");
                        salary = scan.nextInt();
                    }while(!(salary>=10000));
                    ft.salary.add(salary);
                }

                String status = "active";
                break;


            }
        }while(choice!=4);

    }

    void view(){
        //for(int i=1, j=0; i<)
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new Main();
    }

}
```

My superclass called Employee

```
    package labweek7;

    import java.util.Vector;

    public abstract class Employee {

        public String name;
        public int age;
        public String role;
        public String type;

        Vector<String> empName = new Vector<>();
        Vector<Integer> empAge = new Vector<>();
        Vector<String> empRole = new Vector<>();
        Vector<String> empType = new Vector<>();

        public Employee(String name, int age, String role, String type) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.role = role;
            this.type = type;
        }

    }
```

My EmployeeFullTime ( sub class 1)
        package labweek7;

```
    import java.util.Vector;

    public class EmployeeFullTime extends Employee{

        Vector<Integer> salary = new Vector<>(); 

        public EmployeeFullTime(String name, int age, String role, String type) {
            super(name, age, role, type); 
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
```

and my employeeparttime (sub class 2)

```
package labweek7;

import java.util.Vector;

public class EmployeePartTime extends Employee{

    Vector<Integer> pay = new Vector<>();
    Vector<Integer> hour = new Vector<>();

    public EmployeePartTime(String name, int age, String role, String type) {
        super(name, age, role, type);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

When I want to input employee name, it gives me NULLpointer exception on  emp.empName.add(name); line. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your code uses the `emp` variable at that point before it has been initialized.   Since an uninitialized reference variable contains `null`, that causes an NPE.

Comment: 1) You can either initialize it in the declaration, or by assigning a non-null value to it.  2) Anywhere before you use it.  But you should be able to work out where.  (I can't understand the logic of your code, or what it is **supposed to do**, so I can't tell you exactly where.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting exception because emp is null.
 You need to initialize your emp object in the main method first:

```
Employee emp = new EmployeeFullTime();
```

For the above statement to work, you should have default constructor in your EmployeeFullTime and Employee class.

Do the same for other objects ft and pt too.

```
 EmployeeFullTime ft = new EmployeeFullTime ();
 EmployeePartTime pt = new EmployeePartTime();
```

Comment: how about this line  pt.pay.add(pay); I am also getting the NullPointerException. Thank you